# WordPress different page templates for different categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm having a problem with wordpress. Let me explain it; i have 3 main categories on my wordpress site.

1. Blog
2. Developer Articles
3. Help

And now i need 3 page templates to list them. I can do it with custom page by listing posts by these categories but when users click subcategories it will not work.

For example;

If the url is like: /blog/general i'd like to show blog page. 
if i create custom page like /blog and list blog posts thats ok but as i said it will not work for /blog/general

I need something to detect url and get a page template by url. Or is it even possible?

Btw i'm good with php, html and css but i just started to use wordpress 2 weeks ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Wordpress rewrite rules to have the URLs you want connect to the correct URLs. Here is some example text that you can add to your functions.php file.

```
<?php
  function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^nutrition/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?page_id=12&food=$matches[1]&variety=$matches[2]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
?>
```

You can learn more about this function at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

Comment: Thanks a lot man, i'll try it tomorrow at work and i'll let you know the result.